# How to format a column with number decimal with max and min in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string, datagridview

I want to format the decimal places displayed and captured in a DataGridView, I have a minimum number of decimal places and a maximum number of decimal places.
For example:

```
If caught, "120.0" display "120.00"
If caught "120.01" display "120.01"
If caught "120,123" display "120,123"
If caught "120.1234" display "120.1234"
If caught "120.12348" display "120.1235" (round)
```

In the DataGridView column "txtcDecimal" has the property (from the designer)

```
txtcDecimal.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";

txtcDecimal.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00##";  // IS ANSWER. I do not work for an event that interfered
```

the mask "0.00##" work as "n2" only get 2 decimals
which does the correct rounding to two decimal places but just do not like what I need (as I show in the example)

How I can do it in a simple manner without consuming many resources?

**Thanks harlam357 & Tom Garske**

Comment: In your third example did you specify a comma (,) on purpose to denote a whole number or was that a typo?

Comment: Please see that I updated my answer to show how it was implemented in Forms.  Glad to see you got it to work!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To format between 2 and 4 decimal places you can use a custom format string.

```
txtcDecimal.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00##"
```

To go a bit further...

```
public partial class Form1
{
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      var list = new List<Data>();
      list.Add(new Data { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = 1.2 });
      list.Add(new Data { Prop1 = 2, Prop2 = 1.234567 });

      dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Prop1", "Prop1");
      dataGridView1.Columns["Prop1"].DataPropertyName = "Prop1";
      dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Prop2", "Prop2");
      dataGridView1.Columns["Prop2"].DataPropertyName = "Prop2";
      dataGridView1.Columns["Prop2"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00##";
      dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
   }

   class Data
   {
      public int Prop1 { get; set; }
      public double Prop2 { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To format between 2 and 4 decimal places you can use a custom format string. (As provided by Harlam357)

```
txtcDecimal.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00##"
```

I verified it with the following simple console application:

```
        double myDouble = 13.1;
        double myDouble2 = 13.12345;
        Console.WriteLine(myDouble.ToString("0.00##"));
        Console.WriteLine(myDouble2.ToString("0.00##"));
        Console.Read();
```

The output was:

```
13.10
13.1235
```

Harlam's answer is clearly correct....

**UPDATE:** This is how I implemented it in forms:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("a");
        dt.Rows.Add(123.4);
        dt.Rows.Add(123.45);
        dt.Rows.Add(123.456);
        dt.Rows.Add(123.4567);
        dt.Rows.Add(123.45678);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellFormatting);
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
        {
            double d = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
            e.Value = d.ToString("0.00##");
        }
    }
```

**SOURCE:** http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/95e7e7ef-2e71-412f-abe5-ffbee2c12c18/

**OUTPUT:**

[image: Example Output from application]

Comment: in console application works but in DataGridview columns not work.
I am try this in the event _CellFormating

Comment: What does it output or show in the DataGridview using this string?  "does not work" is not clear.

Comment: is not working properly, the mask "0.00##" work as "n2" only get 2 decimals

Comment: thank you so much, I really liked your example, I was wrong, between the 2000 lines of code I saw that another event was interfering.

Comment: It is easy to lose that sometimes.  :) Glad you could get it to work.  I also learned a lot on this, great question!

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom formatter.

```
public class MyFormatProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter  
{  
   public object GetFormat(Type formatType)  
   {  
     if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))  
        return this;  
     else  
        return null;  
   }  

   public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)  
   {  
     // Check whether this is an appropriate callback               
     if (!this.Equals(formatProvider))  
        return null;  

     //if argument/ value is null we return empty string  
     if (arg == null)  
        return null;  

     string resultString = arg.ToString();  

     //transform resultString any way you want (could do operations based on given format parameter)  

     //return the resultant string  
     return resultString;  
   }  
}
```

**SOURCE:** [How to custom format data in datagridview during databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117210/how-to-custom-format-data-in-datagridview-during-databinding)