# Formatting datagridview cell to 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

Basically I have a datagridview which displays data from a datatable. Each cell in the datatable is a decimal with roughly 10 decimal points, how can I use the datagridview to display this data to 2 decimal points?

I have tried this (what I found in other questions):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < this.dgvDynamics1.Columns.Count; i++)
            this.dgvDynamics1.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

but it doesn't work

If you need any more info let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229590/how-to-format-a-column-with-number-decimal-with-max-and-min-in-datagridview) may help you on your way

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
this.dgvDynamics1.Columns.Items[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00##";
this.dgvDynamics1.Columns.Items[i].ValueType = GetType(Double)
```

Comment: That seems to be the answer for everyone else but it doesn't work for me

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: no difference, I am going to try and use the formatting event handler

Comment: Try Adding Items[] above - not sure if you can get columns by index

Comment: I was able to make this work, without the second line in the example.

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
private void dgvList_CellFormatting(object sender,DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 6 || e.ColumnIndex == 8)
        {
            e.CellStyle.Format = "N2";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but for the record, this should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.dgvDynamics1.Columns.Count; i++)
    this.dgvDynamics1.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dgvDynamics1.Columns)
   {
  column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
   }
```

if you need specific columns you can use :

```
this.dgvDynamics1.Columns[YourCoulmnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I always change the format in the designer with no problems. Here's how:

[image: Here the procedure]