# How to use Math.Round option for round to 2 decimals if we used convert.ToDouble option in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would like to know how to use Math.Round option to round to 2 decimals of following insert query which consist of Convert.ToDouble options

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                con.sqlquery(@"Insert into TBL_PO_Cart(PO_No,ISBN_No,OrderQuantity,UnitPrice,Total) values('" + txtPONo.Text + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value) + "')");
                con.mysqlconnection();
                con.nonquery();
            }
```

and also need to know how to display only 2 decimals in datagridview column.

Answer (score 0):

take a look here.

[How to format a column with number decimal with max and min in DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229590/how-to-format-a-column-with-number-decimal-with-max-and-min-in-datagridview)