# Display Lesson Names instead of Lesson Codes in the grid with BindingSource or with some other method

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, datagridview

I have a data in the database. And I read this data and display it in the grid. For this I use `DataSet, SqlDataAdapter, BindingSource and DataGridView`.
The table is like below.

```
+---------+------------+-------------+
|   NAME  |   SURNAME  | LESSON_CODE |
+---------+------------+-------------+
|  Joe    |  Black     |  110        |          
|  Mia    |  Sommers   |  120        | 
|  Hasan  |  Almalik   |  100        | 
|  Anna   |  Volkova   |  100        | 
|  Robert |  Jackson   |  115        | 
|  Tony   |  Bernard   |  120        | 
|  Diana  |  Albert    |  115        | 
|  Tom    |  Bruce     |  110        |
+---------+------------+-------------+
```

I read this data from table like this sql query.

```
string sql = "SELECT Name, Surname, Lesson_Code as Lesson FROM Class"
SqlDataAdapter adapter  = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds,"Class");

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(ds,"Class");
gridClass.DataSource = bs;
```

Ok. There is not any problem.
But I dont want to show Lesson Codes in the grid. I have a list of Lessons and Lesson codes.

```
100 - MATH  
110 - GEOMETRY  
115 - BIOLOGY  
120 - ASTRONOMY  
etc.
```

I dont store this list in the database. If I store this list in the table I can solve this problem with sql query with table joining.
But i dont want do this.  I dont want to use sql query. I want to do this from code.
So I think I can solve this problem with BindingSource. But I dont know how? Or may be there is another way?

Comment: So do you have another table with lesson names in?

Comment: @namco It looks like your question interrupted unexpectedly at "I dont store this list in"

Comment: It may be possible to solve with formatting. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2117210/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying you have another table with lesson names associated with codes then you have to do a join. Your query should look something like this.

`SELECT a.Lesson_Name, b.Surname, b.Name
FROM LessonTable a, Class b
WHERE a.Lesson_Code = b.Lesson_Code`

Comment: I dont want to use sql query. Is there any way to do this with code?

Comment: No I dont have. I dont want to solve it with sql query.

Comment: The condition "don't use sql query" is clearly mentioned in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to bind your results into a datatable.

Then using a new datatable, populate it with the previous datatable and your Lesson column