# C# DataGridView - Custom format for a specific column

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, datagridview

I'm currently retrieving data from a MySQL database and displaying them in a `DataGridView`. One of the columns is `gender(int)` with `1` signifying **Male** and `2` signifying **Female**. I want the DataGridView to display **Male** or **Female** instead of just `1` and `2`.

Is it good practice to format the data ahead in the MySQL query? I'm thinking of *adorning* the retrieved data in `DataGridView` instead of changing the data retrieved. But let me hear your thoughts.

Comment: you can create a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and cell will display the value matching the data.

Comment: I'm loading the grid from a query with DataTable. I cannot set the cells to combobox because they don't exist at development time. (?)

Comment: I say always format on the presentation layer especially date & time values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to custom format data in datagridview during databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117210/how-to-custom-format-data-in-datagridview-during-databinding)

Answer (score 1):

In the below sample, i created a column dynamically  and added to my data grid. Now once the data table is binding to the Grid, it will choose the correct values.

```
         try
            {
                dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                //source for combo box
                var items = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                items.Add("Male", 1);
                items.Add("FeMale", 2);

                //new combobox column for the GRID
                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn gender = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                gender.DisplayMember = "Key";
                gender.ValueMember = "Value";
                gender.DataSource = new BindingSource(items, null);
                gender.HeaderText = "Gender";
                gender.DataPropertyName = "Gender";
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(gender);

                //Data for the GRID
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(int));
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1 });
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2 });
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2 });
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2 });
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1 });
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

This give the below output

[image: Output]

Comment: @Donovan please accept the answer if  it resolves your issue.

Comment: I'd like the column to contain only text and not combobox? is there a way for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is visual basic code. Not sure if it is good practice to format the data beforehand though..

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles 
GridView1.RowDataBound

If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
Dim gender As String = 
Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells(columnnumber).Text).Trim()
If gender= "1" Then
e.Row.Cells(columnnumber).Text = "Male"
Else if gender="2" Then
e.Row.Cells(columnnumber).Text="Female"   `

End If
End Sub
```

fieldtype: 
    asp:BoundField DataField="Zone"

Translated using : https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)) {
        string gender = Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells[columnnumber].Text).Trim();
        if ((gender == "1")) {
            e.Row.Cells[columnnumber].Text = "Male";
        }
        else if ((gender == "2")) {
            e.Row.Cells[columnnumber].Text = "Female";
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there a C# equivalent of that? Although I get the gist of the code, I've never used VB before.