# How to set the currency format for one cell ONLY

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have DB table that consist of two columns(Price(int)  and Currency(nverchar))
The cells of Price column is formatted depending on what currency is in the second column(cell).
For example:
In DB

| PRICE | CURRENCY |
| --- | --- |
| 12000 | USD |
| 20000 | EUR |

The user should see a formatted view in the DataGrid. For example:

| PRICE | CURRENCY |
| --- | --- |
| $12,000.00 | USD |
| €20,000.00 | EUR |

How can I do this?

> I ​need to do this in Form_load or by a funk that will be called there. I mean: I need to check for all rows and if row[0].cells2 or row[1].cells[2]... contains 'usd' then i need change format the first cell of this row

Is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional DataGridView Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067068/conditional-datagridview-formatting)

Comment: Using the DataGrid's CellFormatting event you could check the value of the Currency column and apply your formatting from there. [DataGrid Cell Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117210/how-to-custom-format-data-in-datagridview-during-databinding) ... [DataGrid Customize Data Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-data-formatting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @JohnG  user interface displayed like this   https://imgur.com/a/Il7dfyq
Textbox cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the grid’s data source is to be set, then… maybe… you could throw this into the grids `CellFormating` event. However, it should be clear that in the long run, the cell will get formatted many-many more times than necessary. I think we can do better. We can not “format” the cell until either 1) the user changes the `Currency` cell, or 2) new data is loaded into the grid.

The first part is trivial… wire up the grids `CellValueChanged` event. If the cell value that changed is a `Currency` cell… then, check the "new" value and format the `Price` cell accordingly.

This works when the user changes a `Currency` cells value, however, it does not work when the data is loaded. Therefore, a simple loop through the grid’s rows should solve that issue. Since we need to set the `Price` cells format in two different places, I suggest creating a method that takes a `DataGridViewRow` and formats the “Price” cell for the given row. It may look something like…

```
private void FormatAmountCell(DataGridViewRow row) {
  if (!row.IsNewRow && row.Cells["Currency"].Value != null) {
    string currency = row.Cells["Currency"].Value.ToString();
    DataGridViewCell cellToFormat = row.Cells["Price"];
    switch (currency) {
      case "EUR":
        cellToFormat.Style.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
        break;
      default:
        cellToFormat.Style.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

With this helper we can then use it in the grids wired up `CellValueChanged` event.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  FormatAmountCell(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
}
```

In addition, a small method that loops through the grids rows and sets each “Price” cells format. We will call this after the data is loaded into the grid.

```
private void FormatAmountCellForAllRows() {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    FormatAmountCell(row);
  }
}
```

Putting all this together for testing may look something like…

```
DataTable GridTable;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
  GridTable = GetData();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable;
  dataGridView1.Columns["Price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
  FormatAmountCellForAllRows();
}

private DataTable GetData() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
  dt.Columns.Add("Currency", typeof(string));
  Random rand = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dt.Rows.Add(rand.NextDouble() * 100, (rand.Next(2) == 0 ? "USD" : "EUR"));
  }
  return dt;
}
```

Now you can sleep well knowing the formatting is never done unnecessarily.